# How to get the selectManyCheckbox row entire values to the list using JSF and datatables

Tags: jsf

Select Many Check box items to Cart :

1. Declare check box first column of data
2. Declare the command button to the above the data
3. Once user click the check box current row data add to the list and this list data go to the  Cart page
4. On click the check box current row data add to the list and on submit the button the entire list data go to the Cart page.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Havê you tried primefaces?

Answer (score 0):

You can use primefaces datatable component for select one or more rows from a table and send this information to everywhere.

Take an example of this in [showcase (the datatable have many others options too)](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/datatable/selection.xhtml).